# How to pass Java objects from one class to another class

Tags: java, hibernate, class, object

I have 3 classes, a main class, a products class and a database class.
my question is how do I pass an object from my products class to my database class and run a methods on it.

```
products class

private int product_id;
private String product_name;
private Double product_price;

//getters and setters

public void contructObjects() {
//using JSoup to scrape data from the web and form objects in a loop here.
}


database class
//using hibernate

public void initialise () {
//code that configures connection and other stuff
}

public void addproduct() {
//starts connection to database
Products product = new Products();
product.contructOjects();  //database class runs method in products class, get objects and hold them here.
}

public void shutdown() {
//stops session
}


main class

Database database = new Database();
database.initialise();
database.addproduct(); //main class gets obejcts held in database class stores them in databse.
database.shutdown();
```

Answer (score 0):

can change `public void contructObjects()` from only execute commands into `public List<(Your Object Datatype)> contructObjects()` that will return value :

```
public List<(Your Object Datatype)> contructObjects() {
   List<(Your Object Datatype)> listObject = new ArrayList<>();
   //using JSoup to scrape data from the web and form objects in a loop here.
   //insert data from web into list, listObject.add(data);
   return listObject;
}
```

and then in database class can get the product list object value and may use it for any purpose :

```
public void addproduct() {
   Products product = new Products();
   List<(Your Object Datatype)> listObject = product.contructOjects();//may use listObject for any purpose 

}
```